# Publicly available ical

Tags: calendar, outlook, icalendar

Are there more sites similar to http://icalshare.com/ ? I'd like to have a collection of sites that share the iCalendar file format for exchanging data between calendaring programs.  Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, with poor wording, typos, and omitted words.

Do you want to publish your calendar or subscribe?

Are you referring to Apple's [iCal](http://www.apple.com/support/ical/) program to manage one's personal schedule? Or are you referring to the [iCalendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar) standard for exchanging data between calendaring programs?

[iCalShare](http://icalshare.com/) is a web site for sharing calendars.

Apple's [OS X Lion Server](http://www.apple.com/macosx/server/) includes "iCal Server 3" for serving calendars to client calendaring apps.

Answer (score 0):

Google has a bunch of "interesting calendars" 
http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?answer=37098

Some of them are really fun to subscribe to.

I like the earth seasons calendar and
"eccentric holidays" which I cannot see on that list but is there somewhere try 
   https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?src=0bajvp6gevochc6mtodvqcg9o0@group.calendar.google.com

Any of the websites that use my wordpress plugin amr-events also generally have their own publicly available ics files.

I give some of them free publicity here:
http://icalevents.com/#live